# Code inside javascript function separated with commas instead of semicolons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to understand the behaviour of a jQuery plugin but I don't understand the way it is coded. I did my best to no avail. Could you please give me a link explaining this way of coding?

```
    (function($) {
        $.widget("ui.chatbox", {
        ....
         _create: function() {
                    var self = this,
                    options = self.options,
                    title = options.title || "No Title",

                    uiChatbox = (self.uiChatbox = $('<div></div>'))
                    .appendTo(document.body)
                           }
        .... 
     }(jQuery));
```

PS: The whole code is a widget created by the jQuery UI Widget Factory. You can see the whole code [`here`](http://magma.cs.uiuc.edu/wenpu1/js/jquery.ui.chatbox.js).

In the official documentation [example](https://jqueryui.com/widget/), the `_create` content is separated by semicolon, what is usual (for me). Help is appreciated.

Comment: these are comma-separated local variable declarations (and their value assignments) in one `var` statement

Comment: Here is a good tutorial: https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/how-to-use-the-widget-factory/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Comment: Thank you very much. I undestand now.

Comment: note also that compilers like closure will also turn expressions into comma-continued expressions, in an effort to save space, so it's not always just a var statement that does this pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript, when declaring new variables with the `var` keyword, you can separate each declaration by commas. Which allows you to only use the `var` keyword once. Its a sort of short-hand.

For example:

```
var self = this,
    options = self.options,
    title = options.title || "No Title",
    uiChatbox = (self.uiChatbox = $('<div></div>')).appendTo(document.body)
```

Is the same as:

```
var self = this;
var options = self.options;
var title = options.title || "No Title";
var uiChatbox = (self.uiChatbox = $('<div></div>')).appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it. basics I never started from. :(

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 2):

These are comma-separated local variable declarations (and their value assignments) in one `var` statement. Equivalent to:

```
var self = this;
var options = self.options;
var title = options.title || "No Title";
var uiChatbox = (self.uiChatbox = $('<div></div>')).appendTo(document.body);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is it. basics I never started from. :(

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, you can define multiple variables in one var statement by separating each `variable = value` statement with a comma and placing a semicolon at the end. You could replace those commas with semicolons and place `var` before all of the other `variable = value` statements and the code would function in essentially the same way.

Comment: Thank you, this is it. basics I never started from. :(

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can declare multiple variables in one statement like this:

```
var a, b, c;
```

You can also initialize a variable at the same time you declare it:

```
var a = 5;
```

And you can combine those two:

```
var a = 5, b = "Hello", c = 42;
```

and for readability you can split it across multiple lines:

```
var a = 5,
    b = "Hello",
    c = 42;
```